# Accessing Environment Variables in a Python Application on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-cloud-run

I have a Python project that I've deployed to Google Cloud Run. Everything works fine until I try to add and access an environment variable. I get an error when attempting to split the variable into an array using the .split(',') function. Here's the relevant code:

```
sheet_ids = os.environ.get('SHEET_IDS_PASSLIST').split(',')
```

And here is the error message from the logs:

[image]

I have added SHEET_IDS_PASSLIST as an environment variable in my revision on Google Cloud Platform with appropriate values.

[image]

However, the error suggests that os.environ.get('SHEET_IDS_PASSLIST') is returning None, indicating that the environment variable isn't being found.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Google cloud has a lot of products/services. Which one are you using?

Comment: The service I used is Cloud Run

Comment: Editing environment variables creates a new revision. Have you checked that the revision receiving traffic is the one with the environment variable set?